# How to use xsl varaible in regex element matches

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I need to do validation using XSL variable and Regex pattern. The variable holds the value of two elements text. Basically the validation is if the XSL variable values (new & 202) are not present in the url the error message should be thrown.

**XSL File**

```
<xsl:variable name="XYZ" select="lower-case(//xyz/text())"/>
<xsl:variable name="BCD" select="lower-case(//bcd/text())"/>

<xsl:template match="//url[@url!='https://www.mvcf/journals/\*$XYZ*/2021/\$BCD.']">
<xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="saxon:line-number()"/>:<xsl:value-of select="saxon:column-number()"/> the url aatribute does not contains xyz and bcd values </xsl:message>

</xsl:template>
```

**Input Xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <test>sdfsdf<xyz>new</xyz><rey>#01</rey><bcd>202</bcd> </test>
<url url="https://www.mvcf/journals/ytre/2021/202.csv" />
```

Comment: If you want to use regular expressions in XSLT 2 or later you can do so using the XPath 2 or later `matches` function e.g. `url[not(matches(@url, concat('https://www.mvcf/journals/', $XYZ, '/2021/', $BCD, '.')))]`. As your question has a verbal description "are not present" and the XSLT code seems pseudo/fantasy syntax I might not have written the right expression to implement the exact check you need but adapt that as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Basically the validation is if the XSL variable values (new & 202) are not present in the url the error message should be thrown.

This could be accomplished without regex by:

```
<xsl:template match="url[not(contains(@url, $XYZ) and contains(@url, $BCD))]">
```

If you want to hardcode the other parts of the URL, then:

```
<xsl:template match="url[@url!=concat('https://www.mvcf/journals/', $XYZ, '/2021/', $BCD)]">
```

---

Untested, because no code to test with was provided.

Comment: The URL has .csv at the end some times .csv might be pdf or xls or some other document. So how to use that in the concat

Comment: You could use `[starts-with(@url, concat(...))]`.